# How much suspended weight and how far down would it need to be lowered in order to generate 100 kWh?

Tags: batteries, motor, torque, gravity

I am working on a 100 kWh capacity gravity battery bank.
How much suspended weight and how far down would it need to be lowered in order to generate 100 kWh?
How many kWh would it take to lift the weight back up?
What style of motor/generator can do this? It's being used both as the generator and the motor. Any thoughts on high torque direct drive?

Comment: Are you asking what the formula for potential energy is, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Pedant - W is capital to give due deference to James Watt.

Comment: While we're at it, the k in kW is small (being the SI prefix for thousand, not the Kelvin unit of temperature)

Comment: How many kilowatts it needs to charge it back up depends on the time you want to use for charging. That's what kilowatt-hours are for.

Comment: No, but now that you taught me what that is... I looked it up and found that I need...165 us tons traveling 800ft. To produce 100kwh. Does that sound right?

Comment: The potential energy formula helped and its is k for kilo and I missed the h to make kWh.

Comment: It would take a lot more kWh to restore height than it generates unless you happen to have free energy from a forklift with the capacity to lift 150 car batteries at 0.667 kWh per battery but for a flashlight OK not f or a crew to lift all the batteries to a height of “E=667*3600[Joules]= mgh/efficiency net” per battery.

Comment: @EricHeagan Yes, just type "(165 us tons)*(earth's gravity)*(800 feet)" into google's search bar and it will report "357935938 joules" which appears to be about what Mattman944 wrote. If you have high cliffs where you live, you can get by with less mass. I've got at most 150 feet to work with here, so I'd need more mass. You write "I am working on a 100kwh capacity gravity battery bank." But then you needed to be taught m*g*h? You'll need to learn a lot more, I fear.

Comment: E=mgh. Job done.

Comment: At what rate do you want to charge/discharge the storage? Anyway, flywheel energy storage is readily available to buy, with all the problems sorted out for you.

Comment: Maybe this  [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumped-storage_hydroelectricity) shows what you are looking for:

Comment: The rate would probably be c/3-c/4. But since its a mechanical battery it can be any rate that's practical to design.

Comment: The fly wheel design works. But I'm curious about what happens during a large earthquake.. it could be catastrophic. Pumped storage is bound by location and geology. Utility scale lithium batteries are only good for 20-30 years max then they get scrapped. I'm seeking out alternative battery ideas and trying to get some rough data to share with local engineers who might want to work on this. Thanks for the answers. Now I'm working on the kilo watt cost comparison over a time span of 50 years with lithium batteries.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify height or weight to get an answer. Here I have assumed a height.

Motors efficiency is somewhere around 90-95%.

I doubt that what you are attempting to do is practical. Potential energy of water reservoirs has been used to store energy on a large scale.

[formula from wikipedia]

[image]

Comment: That's only 1700 Ultrablocks. I just used 200 of them to form a small structual wall. At the price I paid, 1700 would total up near US$110k. But that's not out of reach. Now... lifting them 10 m? "Give me a lever long enough and a fulcrum on which to place it, and I shall move the world." With enough leverage, anything can be done! I do think the OP needs some spare cash, though, and the right land to buy. Nice calcs. +1

Comment: This company is proposing it for energy storage: https://energyvault.com for up to 80MWh.

Comment: Square earth proponents would just dangle a weight over the edge. Problem solved.

Comment: For visualisation, that's a smallish cargo ship. https://shipsforsale.su/en/catalog/tankers/dwt_3000_5000/

Comment: 1700 individual "cells"

Answer (score 3):

For the electrical energy,

$$\begin{aligned} 
100\ \text {kWh} &= 100 \times 3600 \ \text {kWs}  \\
&= 360,000 \ \text {kWs} \\
&= 36 \times 10^4\ \text {kJ} \\ 
&= 36 \times 10^7\ \text {J} 
\end{aligned}$$
(Note proper capitalisation of SI prefixes and units.)

Potential energy is given by \$ E = mgh \$.

Rounding *g* to 10 m/s<sup>2</sup> we get \$ mh = 36 \times 10^6 \ \text {kg.m} \$.

Example: Say we had a 72 m height available. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
 m &= \frac {36 \times 10^6} {72} \\
&= 0.5 \times 10^6 \ \text {kg} \\
&= 500 \ \text T 
\end{aligned}$$

This all assumes 100% efficiency. I don't have efficiency figures but would estimate that 80 to 90% should be achievable which would mean that you'd get maybe 80 to 90 kWh from the calculated drop and it would take 125 to 111 kWh to lift the weight up again. Overall efficiency would be 64% to 81%.

[image]

*Figure 1. From left to right, Energy Vault’s tower fully “charged,” at partial levels of charge, and with its capacity fully expended. Source: [Energy Vault](https://energyvault.com/commercial-demonstration-unit/).*