# Understanding sporadic charging of a gravity battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

This question is just for the curiosity, trying to have a more intuitive (to me) mental model for understanding energy storage and recovery.

Say a cellphone battery might have a capacity of 11Wh. If I want to replace the chemical battery with a gravity battery, then by `e = mgh` and with help from [the convenient dimensional analysis of WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cbrt%5B%28%2811Wh%2F%2890%25*8ft*9.8%28m%2Fs%5E2%29%29%29%2F%287.3%28g%2Fcm%5E3%29%29%29%2F%281m%5E3%29%5Dm%20in%20ft)

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{\frac{11Wh}{(90\%*8ft*9.8(m/s^2)}}{7.3(g/cm^3)}} \approx 2ft$$

I would need a steel cube (7.3g/cm³ density) about 2ft to a side lifted 8ft up on Earth at 90% efficiency.

If I charge this gravity battery with an inconsistent source such as some solar panels, what is the battery charger mechanism responsible for? A motor generator would need to be geared and back-drivable to get the RPMs into a usable range, right?  Even if the battery is not charged, the charging mechanism would have to prioritize powering the phone with the available power, using any available battery charge to supplement if necessary.  When there is a surplus of energy available and the battery is not "full" then the surplus should lift the load. There would need to be a break of some sort to hold charge? Is there an unavoidable point on the timeline where the motor/generator is being driven too slowly in either direction for such a mechanism to operate?

I realize this "question" is imprecise and not answerable with a particular circuit or value.  I am just wanting someone with an excellent grasp of the concepts (both electrical and mechanical) and a decent imagination to help explain battery charging circuitry using a gravity-battery analog.

[image: Thanks craiyon.com!]

Related to but distinct from: [How much suspended weight and how far down would it need to be lowered in order to generate 100 kWh?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558066/how-much-suspended-weight-and-how-far-down-would-it-need-to-be-lowered-in-order)

Comment: concrete isn't 7.3 g/cm3, it's in the 2.1-2.5 g/cm3 range. 90% is incredibly optimistic for the efficiency of motors / generators in the several watts / 10s of watts sort of range.

Comment: anything that lifts anything and has a generator mode can be a "gravity battery": from a pumped-storage hydroelectric power plant with a gigantic dam, to well, a hammer knotted to a bit of string glued to a cassette drive motor. What the role of anything in that system is is up to **you** to define. We can't invent your device for you, then explain it to you, that's just out of scope.

Comment: thanks.  got my numbers for steel and concrete confused.  regarding efficiency, I was just trying to acknowledge that there are losses.

Comment: I can’t seem to determine the mass of your cube. Also your mixing of units will invalidate your numerical result, stick to meters, kg, joules and seconds

Comment: @Bryan the dimensional analysis can handle the unit conversions, I believe

Comment: @JasonKleban perhaps it can, I can see a bit more of what you're trying to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with gravity batteries:

When they generate power, the weight goes down at a somewhat constant velocity, which means the generator produces a counter-torque equivalent to the torque caused by the weight through the gears. Another way to say it would be the motor, via the gearing, exerts a force on the weight that is equal to the force of its weight, which means the weight does not accelerate but move at constant speed.

Now, if the load needs less power, then the generator will absorb less mechanical power, its current will decrease, and therefore its torque will decrease, which means the weight will accelerate towards the ground.

If the load needs more power, then the motor will absorb more mechanical power, increasing torque, and slowing the weight down.

In other words, it does the exact opposite of what you need. So you need either a CVT transmission (which sinks the project due to cost compared to a Lithium battery) or brakes (which destroy the efficiency).

To charge the battery using the motor and the solar panel, the problem is the same. It will only work if there is enough current to provide enough torque, and in addition the motor's best efficiency rpm range is not that wide.

Gravity batteries work when the load is constant and controlled by the generator itself, for example a [LED lightbulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GravityLight). If the weight accelerates, the generator produces more power, which is consumed by the LED, which decelerates the weight, so it goes at a nice constant speed. And in this case, it can be cranked up by hand.

Comment: I think they also have a coil spring to overcome starting friction in the generator /gearset and ratchet to raise

Comment: Can we not get around the CVT requirement with a flexible power converter?

Comment: Your generator torque / output power rambling is nonsense. This sort of device works with a SMPS converter between the generator and the load. As the load power requirement goes down, the converter draws the same current (so same torque) at a lower voltage (so less speed). It will be designed to have a range of voltage and current over which it's fairly efficient, and below that it can switch to a discontinuous mode.

Comment: I think I'm understanding now that a capacitor of some sort is necessary to smooth out discontinuous discharging/mechanical braking such that when the capacitor is full from surplus solar power, then the capacitor is discharged some to lift the weight. When the capacitor is depleted, then the battery is discharged some to recharge *it*. I guess the extremes of the loads/charges/inertia/mechanical breaking response times would dictate the size of the capacitor and that the efficiencies would be very sensitive to the unavoidable braking mechanism's capabilities.

Comment: @Neil_UK OK that could work, hard to justify the cost for just 11 Wh though

Comment: @bobflux Do you remember the wind-up radio of a very long time ago? Baylis. Now he used a shunt regulator in his original design, and the 'off' switch was a short across the generator. A colleague at work bought one, installed a SMPS regulator instead which improved the spring life 2 or 3 times. How much is a boost regulator? Peanuts compared to the rest of the unit?